# Exported object in CommonJs loses "type" information

Tags: node.js

NodeJs v 4.2.3

I have an object that when printed out shows some "type" information:

```
var foo = new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css');
console.log(foo); // ExtractTextPlugin { filename: '[name].css', options: {}, id: 1 }`
```

first question: how is ExtractTextPlugin being printed? Is it the name of the function that I am calling with "new"?

However, when I export the foo object (in my case via

```
module.exports = { plugins: [ new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css') }};
```

and I console.log the object, it loses the "type" information and instead prints out as

```
{ filename: '[name].css', options: {}, id: 1 }
```

Any idea why that is?

Comment: How `[name.css]` became `[name].css`?

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. I tried it, but works fine to me. I think you should build up an online example (fiddle or anything like).

Comment: "ExtractTextPlugin" isn't `foo.type`, but `foo.constructor.name`

Comment: thefourtheye typo in the question, fixed. @ FlyingFisher, can I use CommonJs in jsfiddle? I'll give it a shot. @ laggingreflex yeah, I got it to work using that, although it doesn't fix my underlying issue - will post that as a separate question. Thanks.

Comment: *"Any idea why that is?"* There is not spec for `console.log`. How environments implement it is completely up to them.

Comment: Thanks Felix - the confusion was that two console.log calls for ostensibly the same object were printing different things. Figured out the actual problem though, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's because of some other stuff I was doing - I was calling lodash.cloneDeep, and that doesn't seem to copy over the constructor name. Oh well.